# Can Nutch crawl video sites?

Tags: video, indexing, nutch

Is it possible to use Nutch to crawl sites with only video files?
Appreciate any insight into this.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's possible with custom plugin for parsing and indexing filter. And also, it's unknown whether are any videos on site before crawl. So you need to enter domains list for crawling manually or implement some algorithm to generate seed domains, for effective crawling.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Can you throw some more light on this? I'm relatively new to Nutch.

Comment: First, read this article on how to build custom plugin http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/07/nutch-custom-plugin-to-parse-and-add.html (my notes: if you want to prevent document from indexing, return null from indexing extension) . For seed urls, see Injecting from here https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial and so on. For filtering urls to follow,  see conf/regex-urlfilter.txt file and regex-urlfilter plugin.

Comment: The site we are trying to crawl is built using flash. Considering that there is a parse-plugin already for swf, if I just include that property in plugin.include.. parse-(html|tika|swf), will it work?? We want the following metadata - title, short_description, video_image into our results (using solr with nutch)

Comment: Probably, you should also implement your own plugin to parse metadata from html page(as I don't sure all data is available in swf metadata) & index it.